# Echo data not being displayed

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am new to php development.I have created a database using phpmyadmin.Now i want all the data to be displayed on the page.But when ever i try to run the file nothing is showing up.I dont know why this is happening.

db_config.php

```
   <?php
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "moviesreview"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server


$con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}
```

db_connect.php

```
   <?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error()) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */

     function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }


}

?>
```

Code

```
  <?php

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$con=new db_connect();

$strQuery="SELECT * FROM `moviesdetails WHERE `recent_upcoming` =0";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$strQuery);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$row_array['movies_id']=$row['movies_id'];
$row_array['movies_name']=$row['movies_name'];
$row_array['movies_description']=$row['movies_description'];
$row_array['movies_time']=$row['movies_time'];
$row_array['movies_release_date']=$row['movies_release_date'];
$row_array['movies_youtube_link']=$row['movies_youtube_link'];
$row_array['recent_upcoming']=$row['recent_upcoming'];
$row_array['movies_image']=$row['movies_image'];
$row_array['movies_actors']=$row['movies_actors'];

array_push($response,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($response);



?>
```

Error what i am getting
[image]

Comment: `<? php` remove the space. `<?php` and missing ending/closing `;` for `$strQuery="SELECT * FROM `moviesdetails WHERE `recent_upcoming` =0"` - $strQuery="SELECT * FROM `moviesdetails WHERE `recent_upcoming` =0"; <= there. Also missing `\`` in `moviesdetails`

Comment: all of those `$row_array` lines are pointless. just have `while($row = ...) { $response[] = $row; }`

Comment: Prepare yourself for the onslaught of PHP whitescreens, notices, and errors. I can't decide what bug to fix first. Among everyone else's suggestions, you haven't even declared `$row_array` as an array anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

- The space between `<?` and `php`
- A missing tick for your table, and a missing semi-colon for your query.
- A missing DB connection link.

Your code:

```
<? php
  ^ space

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$strQuery="SELECT * FROM `moviesdetails WHERE `recent_upcoming` =0"
                                       ^                           ^

$result=mysqli_query($strQuery);
                     ^ no DB connection
```

---

```
<?php

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$strQuery="SELECT * FROM `moviesdetails` WHERE `recent_upcoming` =0";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$strQuery);
```

Using error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled that, including `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

---

You've edited your question. You are mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions. They do not mix.

All `mysql_error` should be `mysqli_error($con)` and `mysql_close()` to `mysqli_close($con)`

---

**Edit:**

Replace the entire contents of `db_connect.php` with the following:

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "moviesdetails"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server


$con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}
```

---

**Edit #2:**

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $response[] = $row;
    $row['movies_id'];
    $row['movies_name'];
    $row['movies_description'];
    $row['movies_time'];
    $row['movies_release_date'];
    $row['movies_youtube_link'];
    $row['recent_upcoming'];
    $row['movies_image'];
    $row['movies_actors'];

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: ok done , now am getting error at this line "while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))"

Comment: @user3917131 Reload answer and look under **Edit #2:**

Comment: did as u said but getting this error " Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\MovieReviews\get_recent_movies.php on line 14"

Comment: @user3917131 I'm at a loss at this point. The `WHERE` clause with `=0` make sure that column is an `int`. If not, do `='0'` other than that, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have missing connection link as parameter in your `mysqli_query()` function. Should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection_link, $strQuery);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

---

`$connection_link` will have in this case following format:

```
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$connection_link = new DB_CONNECT();
```

But as @Fred -ii- said in comments, you have some syntax errors in PHP and SQL query too.

Your DB class is badly designed, you should store connection link in property and making queries through this class.

Comment: `$connection_link = mysqli_connect(...);`

Comment: Problem solved, finally. Read over the comments under my answer. I worked pretty hard on this one lol